# Can I validate json Schema draft-7 with tv4?

Tags: json, jsonschema, tv4

I have to upgrade a javascript application that validates json with json schema. The old version is using tv4 to validate json schema draft 4. I need to use draft-7 in the new software.

I just replace a draft-7 json file in the current code. It worked fine at the beginning, but later the app started to show some errors related to tv4.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
...
}
```

My question is can I use tv4 with draft-7. Is there any draft-7 library to replace tv4?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I use ajv library to replace tv4